# merged cells won't remove borders between them

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I wrote function for droping list items:
private void grid1_Drop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock textBlock = e.Source as TextBlock;
            Console.WriteLine("drop item into grid column:{0} row:{1}",
                Grid.GetColumn(textBlock), Grid.GetRow(textBlock));

```
        DataObject item = (((DragEventArgs)e).Data) as DataObject;
        ListBoxItem listItem = item.GetData(typeof(ListBoxItem)) as ListBoxItem;
        Window1 second = new Window1();
        second.ShowDialog();

        //textBlock.Height = textBlock.Height*second.getBrCasova();

        Grid.SetRowSpan(textBlock, second.getBrCasova());

        textBlock.Background = Brushes.Gray;
        string pom = "";
        if(second.getBrCasova() == 1)
            textBlock.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < second.getBrCasova();i++ )
                pom += "\n";
        textBlock.Text = pom + listItem.Content.ToString() + "\n" + second.getUcionica();
        textBlock.TextAlignment = System.Windows.TextAlignment.Center;
        textBlock.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,2,2.5);

    }
```

the problem is, if I get Grid.SetRowSpan(textBlock, second.getBrCasova()), second.getBrCasova>2, borders between cells wont be deleted.

This part of xaml show how I make table of textblocks:

```
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,2,2" Background="Transparent" />
        <Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,2,2" Background="Transparent" />
        <Border Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,2,2" Background="Transparent" />
        <Border Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,2,2" Background="Transparent" />
        <Border Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,2,2" Background="Transparent" />
        <Border Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,2,2" Background="Transparent" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="TextBlock11" AllowDrop="True" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock11_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"></TextBlock>
        <!--<Rectangle Grid.Column="2"
           Grid.Row="1"  
           Stroke="Black"
           Fill="Transparent" />-->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" AllowDrop="True"></TextBlock>
        <!--<Rectangle Grid.Column="3"
           Grid.Row="1"  
           Stroke="Black"
           Fill="Transparent" />-->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" AllowDrop="True"></TextBlock>
        <!--<Rectangle Grid.Column="4"
           Grid.Row="1"  
           Stroke="Black"
           Fill="Transparent" />-->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" AllowDrop="True"></TextBlock>
```

....

How to remove this borders from function? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more information about what it is you are trying to do. Possibly more code as well: what does `getBrCasova` do, for example? You want to "remove borders from function" but it's not clear what you mean by this. Visual borders? On which elements?

Comment: GetBrCasova return number of how many cells will be extended textBlock, and if this number is 2 everything works fine, but if this number is bigger than 2, Grid. SetRowSpan function extend textBlock, but don't remove the borders between them, and I mean visual borders.

Comment: OK, thanks for the extra info. However, I really think that you are more likely to get an answer if you post at least some of your XAML. That way, we can see which elements already have borders. Also, it's still not clear what you are dragging around and what you expect to happen when those things are dropped. I would like to help you but I still don't have enough information to do so.

Comment: I drag elements from the listbox and drop on textblocks in early created table of empty textblocks, and I sometimes I need to expand content on 2,3 or more textblocks, but if I expend more than on two textblocks, visual border between textblocks don't disappear.